# slider images in second modal not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

I have two modals and an image slider in both the modals. while the first modal loads the image slider perfectly... the 2nd modal just shows the loading animation but never loads the slider...
below is my html code :

```js
var sliderOptions=
{
 sliderId: "slider",
 startSlide: 0,
 effect: "series1",
 effectRandom: false,
 pauseTime: 2600,
 transitionTime: 500,
 slices: 12,
 boxes: 8,
 hoverPause: 1,
 autoAdvance: true,
 thumbnailsWrapperId: "thumbs",
 m: false,
 license: "mylicense"
};

var imageSlider=new mcImgSlider(sliderOptions);

/* Menucool Javascript Image Slider v2016.9.27. Copyright www.menucool.com */
function mcImgSlider(i){for(var I=function(a){return document.getElementById(a)},d="length",Q="getElementsByTagName",t=function(e){var a=e.childNodes,c=[];if(a)for(var b=0,f=a[d];b<f;b++)a[b].nodeType==1&&c.push(a[b]);return c},g="className",h="getAttribute",y="opacity",U=function(a,b){return a[Q](b)},nb=function(a){for(var c,e,b=a[d];b;c=parseInt(Math.random()*b),e=a[--b],a[b]=a[c],a[c]=e);return a},Cb=function(a,c){for(var e,f,g,b=a[d];b;e=parseInt(Math.random()*b),f=a[--b],a[b]=a[e],a[e]=f,g=c[b],c[b]=c[e],c[e]=g);return[a,c]},Bb=function(a,c,b){if(a.addEventListener)a.addEventListener(c,b,false);else a.attachEvent&&a.attachEvent("on"+c,b)},P=document,J=window.requestAnimationFrame,W=window.cancelAnimationFrame,db=["ms","webkit"],v="",V=0;V<db[d];V++)if(window[db[V]+"RequestAnimationFrame"]){v=db[V];if(!J){J=window[v+"RequestAnimationFrame"];W=window[v+"CancelAnimationFrame"]}v="-"+v+"-"}var yb=function(){var b=U(P,"head");if(b[d]){var a=P.createElement("style");b[0].appendChild(a);return a.sheet?a.sheet:a.styleSheet}else return 0},sb=function(){var a=yb();if(a)if(typeof a.insertRule!="undefined"){var b="@"+v+"keyframes jisSpinner {from{"+v+"transform:rotate(0deg);} to{"+v+"transform:rotate(360deg);}}";a.insertRule(b,0);var c="#"+i.sliderId+" .bgLayer{position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;}";a.insertRule(c,0);var d="#"+i.sliderId+"::before {"+v+"animation:jisSpinner 0.6s linear infinite;transform:translate3d(0,0,0);content:'';position:absolute;left:50%;top:50%;width:40px;height:40px;margin-top:-20px;margin-left:-20px;border-width:4px;border-color:black rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);border-style:solid;border-radius:50%;}";a.insertRule(d,0)}else a.addRule("#"+i.sliderId+" .bgLayer","position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;")};sb();var c="style",H="display",Eb="visibility",r="width",q="height",O="top",B="background",p="undefined",Fb="marginLeft",F="appendChild",l="parentNode",k="nodeName",S="innerHTML",cb="offsetWidth",u=setTimeout,z=clearTimeout,w="indexOf",N="setAttribute",bb="removeChild",L=function(){this.d=[];this.b=null},zb=function(){var b=50,a=navigator.userAgent,c;if((c=a[w]("MSIE "))!=-1)b=parseInt(a.substring(c+5,a[w](".",c)));if(a[w]("Safari")!=-1&&a[w]("Chrome")==-1)b=300;if(a[w]("Opera")!=-1)b=400;return b},T=zb()<9,ab=/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent),K=function(a,b){if(a){a.o=b;if(T)a[c].filter="alpha(opacity="+b*100+")";else a[c][y]=b}};L.a={f:function(a){return-Math.cos(a*Math.PI)/2+.5},h:function(b,a){return Math.pow(b,a*2)},j:function(b,a){return 1-Math.pow(1-b,a*2)}};L.prototype={k:{c:i.transitionTime,a:function(){},b:L.a.f,d:1},m:function(h,d,g,c){for(var b=[],i=g-d,j=g>d?1:-1,f=Math.ceil(60*c.c/1e3),a,e=1;e<=f;e++){a=d+c.b(e/f,c.d)*i;if(h!=y)a=Math.round(a);b.push(a)}b.e=0;return b},n:function(){this.b==null&&this.p()},p:function(){this.q();var a=this;this.b=J?J(function(){a.p()}):window.setInterval(function(){a.q()},15)},q:function(){var a=this.d[d];if(a){for(var c=0;c<a;c++)this.o(this.d[c]);while(a--){var b=this.d[a];if(b.d.e==b.d[d]){b.c();this.d.splice(a,1)}}}else{if(J&&W)W(this.b);else window.clearInterval(this.b);this.b=null}},o:function(a){if(a.d.e<a.d[d]){var e=a.b,b=a.d[a.d.e];if(a.b==y){if(T){e="filter";b="alpha(opacity="+Math.round(b*100)+")"}}else b+="px";a.a[c][e]=b;a.d.e++}},r:function(e,b,d,f,a){a=this.s(this.k,a);var c=this.m(b,d,f,a);this.d.push({a:e,b:b,d:c,c:a.a});this.n()},s:function(c,b){b=b||{};var a,d={};for(a in c)d[a]=typeof b[a]!==p?b[a]:c[a];return d}};var G=new L,gb=function(){G.d=[];z(m);z(R);m=R=null},xb=function(b){var a=[],c=b[d];while(c--)a.push(String.fromCharCode(b[c]));return a.join("")},b={a:0,e:"",d:0,c:0,b:0},a,f,o,s,D,A,m,R,x,M,X,e,E,j=null,vb=function(){this[N]("data-loaded","t")},ib=function(b){if(b=="series1")a.a=[6,8,15,2,5,14,13,3,7,4,14,1,13,15];else if(b=="series2")a.a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17];else a.a=b.split(/\W+/);a.a.p=i.effectRandom?-1:a.a[d]==1?0:1},Y=function(){a={b:i.pauseTime,c:i.transitionTime,f:i.slices,g:i.boxes,d:i.license,h:i.hoverPause,i:i.autoAdvance,l:i.thumbnailsWrapperId,Ob:function(){typeof beforeSlideChange!==p&&beforeSlideChange(arguments)},Oa:function(){typeof afterSlideChange!==p&&afterSlideChange(arguments)}};if(f)a.m=Math.ceil(f.offsetHeight*a.g/f[cb]);ib(i.effect);a.n=function(){var b;if(a.a.p==-1)b=a.a[Math.floor(Math.random()*a.a[d])];else{b=a.a[a.a.p];a.a.p++;if(a.a.p>=a.a[d])a.a.p=0}if(b<1||b>17)b=15;return b}},qb=["$1$2$3","$1$2$3","$1$24","$1$23","$1$22"],kb=function(){if(b.b!=2){b.b=1;z(m);m=null}},hb=function(){if(b.b!=2){b.b=0;if(m==null&&!b.c&&a.i)m=u(function(){j.y(j.n(b.a+1),0,1)},a.b/2)}},rb=function(){var a=0,b=0,c;while(a<e.length){c=e[a][g]=="lazyImage"||e[a][h]("data-src")||e[a][g][w](" video")>-1&&typeof McVideo!=p;if(c){b=1;break}++a}return b},n=[],jb=function(b){var a=n[d];if(a)while(a--)n[a][g]=a!=b&&n[a].on==0?"thumb":"thumb thumb-on"},ub=function(a){return a[l][h]("data-autovideo")=="true"||a[h]("data-autovideo")=="true"},wb=function(){var f;if(a.l)f=I(a.l);if(f)for(var h=U(f,"*"),e=0;e<h[d];e++)h[e][g]=="thumb"&&n.push(h[e]);var c=n[d];if(c){while(c--){n[c].on=0;n[c].i=c;n[c].onclick=function(){j.y(this.i,ub(this))};if(!ab){n[c].onmouseover=function(){this.on=1;this[g]="thumb thumb-on";a.h==2&&kb()};n[c].onmouseout=function(){this.on=0;this[g]=this.i==b.a?"thumb thumb-on":"thumb";a.h==2&&hb()}}}jb(0)}return c},eb=function(a,e,g,c,b,d,f){u(function(){if(e&&g==e-1){var f={};f.a=function(){j.o()};for(var h in a)f[h]=a[h]}else f=a;typeof b[r]!==p&&G.r(c,"width",b[r],d[r],a);typeof b[q]!==p&&G.r(c,"height",b[q],d[q],a);G.r(c,y,b[y],d[y],f)},f)},lb=function(a){f=a;this.Id=f.id;this.c()},ob=function(e,c){for(var b=[],a=0;a<e[d];a++)b[b[d]]=String.fromCharCode(e.charCodeAt(a)-(c?c:3));return b.join("")},pb=[/(?:.*\.)?(\w)([\w\-])[^.]*(\w)\.[^.]+$/,/.*([\w\-])\.(\w)(\w)\.[^.]+$/,/^(?:.*\.)?(\w)(\w)\.[^.]+$/,/.*([\w\-])([\w\-])\.com\.[^.]+$/,/^(\w)[^.]*(\w)$/],C=function(b){var a=P.createElement("div");a[g]=b;return a},tb=function(b,c){var p=/\/?(SOURCE|EMBED|OBJECT|\/VIDEO|\/AUDIO)/,g=t(f),a=g[d],i;while(a--){i=g[a];(i[k]=="BR"||T&&p.test(i[k]))&&f[bb](i)}g=f.children;var e=g[d];if(b=="shuffle"){var h=[];for(a=0,pos=e;a<pos;a++)h[h.length]=g[a];if(c&&c[d]==e){var o=c[0].parentNode,j=[];for(a=0,pos=e;a<pos;a++)j[j.length]=c[a];var l=Cb(h,j),m=l[0],n=l[1]}else m=nb(h);for(a=0,pos=e;a<pos;a++){f.appendChild(m[a]);n&&o.appendChild(n[a])}b=0}else if(b=="random")b=Math.floor(Math.random()*e);if(b){b=b%e;a=0;while(1)if(a++==b)break;else{f.appendChild(f.children[0]);c&&c[0].parentNode.appendChild(c[0])}}return f.children};lb.prototype={c:function(){if(x)return;o=f[cb];s=f.offsetHeight;var r=t(f),G=r[d];if(a.l){var p=I(a.l);p=p?p.children:0}r=tb(i.startSlide,p);this.M(a.d);var j,n;e=[];while(G--){j=r[G];n=0;j[c][H]="none";if(j[k]=="VIDEO"||j[k]=="AUDIO"){j[c].position="absolute";n=C("video");j[l].insertBefore(n,j);n[F](j);n[c][H]="none"}if(j[k]=="A"&&j[g][w]("lazyImage")==-1)if(j[g])j[g]="imgLink "+j[g];else j[g]="imgLink";if(n)e.push(n);else e.push(j);if(j[g][w](" video")!=-1){this.A(j);this.b(j)}}e.reverse();b.d=e[d];a.m=Math.ceil(s*a.g/o);E=C("sliderInner");f[F](E);A=C("mc-caption");f[F](A);A[c].transition="opacity "+a.c+"ms";var v=this.v();if(e[b.a][k]=="IMG")b.e=e[b.a];else b.e=U(e[b.a],"img")[0];if(e[b.a][k]=="A"||e[b.a][g]=="video")e[b.a][c][H]="block";M[c][B]='url("'+b.e[h]("src")+'") no-repeat';if(typeof getComputedStyle!="undefined"){var y=getComputedStyle(f,null).borderRadius;if(y)M[c].borderRadius=y}D=this.k();this.m();var q=b.e[l],z;if(z=q.aP){this.d(q);if(z===1)q.aP=0}else if(a.i&&b.d>1){u(function(){v.e(1)},0);m=u(function(){v.y(v.n(1),0,1)},a.b+a.c)}if(a.h!=0&&!ab){f.onmouseover=kb;f.onmouseout=hb}},b:function(a){if(typeof McVideo!=p){a.onclick=function(){return this.aP?false:j.d(this)};McVideo.register(a,this)}},A:function(a){if(typeof a.aP===p){var b=a[h]("data-autovideo");if(b=="true")a.aP=true;else if(b=="1")a.aP=1;else a.aP=0}},d:function(c){z(m);m=null;var a=McVideo.play(c,o,s,this.Id);if(a||ab)b.b=2;return false},f:function(){x=C("navBulletsWrapper");for(var e=[],a=0;a<b.d;a++)e.push("<div rel='"+a+"'>"+(a+1)+"</div>");x[S]=e.join("");for(var c=t(x),a=0;a<c[d];a++){if(a==b.a)c[a][g]="active";c[a].onclick=function(){j.y(parseInt(this[h]("rel")),1)}}f[F](x);M=C("bgLayer");f.insertBefore(M,f.firstChild)},g:function(){var d=t(x),a=b.d;while(a--){if(a==b.a)d[a][g]="active";else d[a][g]="";if(e[a][k]=="A"||e[a][g]=="video")e[a][c][H]=a==b.a?"block":"none"}},k:function(){var a=b.e[h]("alt")||"";if(a&&a.substr(0,1)=="#"){var c=I(a.substring(1));a=c?c[S]:""}return a},l:function(){K(A,0)},m:function(){A[S]=D;A[c][Eb]=D?"visible":"hidden";D&&K(A,1)},a:function(a){return a.replace(/(?:.*\.)?(\w)([\w\-])?[^.]*(\w)\.[^.]*$/,"$1$3$2")},o:function(){b.c=0;z(m);m=null;M[c][B]='url("'+b.e[h]("src")+'") no-repeat';var i=this,d=b.e[l];if(typeof d.aP===p)d=0;var f;if(d&&(f=d.aP||X&&/video$/.test(d[g]))){this.d(d);if(f===1)d.aP=0}else if(!b.b&&a.i){var e=this.n(b.a+1);this.e(e);m=u(function(){i.y(e,0,1)},a.b)}a.Oa.call(this,b.a,b.e)},e:function(j){var a=e[j],m=0;if(a[k]=="A"&&a[g][w]("lazyImage")==-1||a[k]=="DIV"&&a[g]=="video"){a=t(a)[0];m=1}if(a[k]!="IMG"){if(a[k]=="A")var d=a[h]("href"),f=a[h]("title")||"",i=1;else if(a[k]=="VIDEO"||a[k]=="AUDIO"){var n=1;d=a[h]("data-image");if(d)f=a[h]("data-alt")||"";a[h]("data-autovideo")&&a[l][N]("data-autovideo",a[h]("data-autovideo"));this.A(a[l]);i=0}else{d=a[h]("data-src");if(d)f=a[h]("data-alt")||"";i=!m}if(f!=null){var b=P.createElement("img");b[N]("data-loaded","f");b[N]("alt",f);b.onload=b.onerror=vb;b[N]("src",d);b[c][H]="none";if(n){a[l].insertBefore(b,a);this.b(a[l],this);if(T){a[l][c][B]="none";a[l][c].cursor="default"}}else a[l].replaceChild(b,a);if(i)e[j]=b}}},p:function(f){if(e[b.a][k]=="IMG")b.e=e[b.a];else b.e=U(e[b.a],"img")[0];var g=b.e[h]("data-loaded");if(g=="f"){u(function(){j.p(f)},200);return}b.c=1;this.g();z(R);D=this.k();this.l();R=u(function(){j.m()},a.c/2);E[S]="";var c=f?f:a.n();a.Ob.apply(this,[b.a,b.e,D,c]);jb(b.a);var d=c<14?this.w(c):this.x();if(c<9||c==15){if(c%2)d=d.reverse()}else if(c<14)d=d[0];if(c<9)this.q(d,c);else if(c<13)this.r(d,c);else if(c==13)this.s(d);else if(c<16)this.t(d,c);else this.u(d,c)},q:function(b,e){for(var f=0,g=e<7?{height:0,opacity:-.4}:{width:0,opacity:0},i={height:s,opacity:1},a=0,h=b[d];a<h;a++){if(e<3)b[a][c].bottom="0";else if(e<5)b[a][c][O]="0";else if(e<7){b[a][c][a%2?"bottom":"top"]="0";g[y]=-.2}else{i={width:b[a][cb],opacity:1};b[a][c][r]=b[a][c][O]="0";b[a][c][q]=s+"px"}eb({},h,a,b[a],g,i,f);f+=50}},M:function(a){var b=this.a(document.domain.replace("www.",""));try{(function(a,c){var e="%66%75%6E%%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%20%65%28%b)*<g/dbmm)uijt-2*<h)1*<h)2*<jg)n>K)o-p**|wbs!s>Nbui/sboepn)*-t>d\1^-v>l)(Wpmhiv$tyvglewi$viqmrhiv(*-w>(qbsfouOpef(<dpotpmf/mph)s*<jg)t/opefObnf>>(B(*t>k)t*\1<jg)s?/9*t/tfuBuusjcvuf)(bmu(-v*<fmtf!jg)s?/8*|wbsr>epdvnfou/dsfbufUfyuOpef)v*-G>mwr5<jg)s?/86*G>Gw/jotfsuCfgpsf)r-G*sfuvso!uijt<69%6F%6E%<jg)s?/9*t/tfuBuusjcvuf)(bmupdvnf%$ou/dsfbufUfy",b=ob(e,a[d]+parseInt(a.charAt(1))).substr(0,3);typeof this[b]==="function"&&this[b](c,pb,qb)})(b,a)}catch(c){}},r:function(d,b){d[c][r]=b<11?"0px":o+"px";d[c][q]=b<11?s+"px":"0px";K(d,1);if(b<11)d[c][O]="0";if(b==9){d[c].left="auto";d[c].right="0px"}else if(b>10)d[c][b==11?"bottom":"top"]="0";if(b<11)var e=0,f=o;else{e=0;f=s}var g={b:L.a.j,c:a.c*1.6,a:function(){j.o()}};G.r(d,b<11?"width":"height",e,f,g)},s:function(b){b[c][O]="0";b[c][r]=o+"px";b[c][q]=s+"px";var d={c:a.c*1.6,a:function(){j.o()}};G.r(b,y,0,1,d)},t:function(b){var t=a.g*a.m,o=0,m=0,i=0,g=0,f=[];f[0]=[];for(var e=0,n=b[d];e<n;e++){b[e][c][r]=b[e][c][q]="0px";f[i][g]=b[e];g++;if(g==a.g){i++;g=0;f[i]=[]}}for(var p={c:a.c/1.3},j=0,n=a.g*2;j<n;j++){for(var h=j,k=0;k<a.m;k++){if(h>=0&&h<a.g){var l=f[k][h];eb(p,b[d],o,l,{width:0,height:0,opacity:0},{width:l.w,height:l.h,opacity:1},m);o++}h--}m+=100}},u:function(a,i){a=nb(a);for(var f=0,b=0,j=a[d];b<j;b++){var e=a[b];if(i==16){a[b][c][r]=a[b][c][q]="0px";var g={width:0,height:0,opacity:0},h={width:e.w,height:e.h,opacity:1}}else{g={opacity:0};h={opacity:1}}eb({},a[d],b,e,g,h,f);f+=20}},v:function(){this.f();this.e(0);return(new Function("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l",function(c){for(var b=[],a=0,e=c[d];a<e;a++)b[b[d]]=String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(a)-4);return b.join("")}("zev$NAjyrgxmsr,|0}-zev$eAjyrgxmsr,f-zev$gAf2glevGshiEx,4-2xsWxvmrk,-?vixyvr$g2wyfwxv,g2pirkxl15-?\u0081?vixyvr$|/}_5a/e,}_4a-/e,}_6a-?\u0081?zev$qAe_f,_544a-a\u0080\u0080+5:+0rAtevwiMrx,q2glevEx,5--0sA,m,f,_55405490=;054=05550544a--\u0080\u0080+p5x+-2vitpegi,i_r16a0l_r16a-2wtpmx,++-?zev$PAh,-?mj,q%AN,+f+/r0s--mj,%P-PAj,-?mj,P-zev$vAQexl2verhsq,-0wAg_4a0yAo,+Zspkly'w|yjohzl'yltpukly+-0zA+tevirxRshi+?mj,w2rshiReqiAA+E+-wAn,w-_4a?mj,vB2<-w2wixExxvmfyxi,+epx+0y-?ipwi$mj,vB2;-zev$uAhsgyqirx2gviexiXi|xRshi,y-0JAp_za?mj,vB2;9-JAJ_za?J_za2mrwivxFijsvi,u0J-?\u0081\u0081\u0081?vixyvr$xlmw?"))).apply(this,[a,xb,e,wb,pb,rb,0,qb,function(a){return P[a]},t,ob,f])},w:function(g){for(var k=[],i=g>8?o:Math.round(o/a.f),l=g>8?1:a.f,f=0;f<l;f++){var j=C("mcSlc"),e=j[c];e.left=i*f+"px";e[r]=(f==a.f-1?o-i*f:i)+"px";e[q]="0px";e[B]='url("'+b.e[h]("src")+'") no-repeat -'+f*i+"px 0%";if(g==10)e[B]='url("'+b.e[h]("src")+'") no-repeat right top';else if(g==12)e[B]='url("'+b.e[h]("src")+'") no-repeat left bottom';e.position="absolute";K(j,0);E[F](j);k[k[d]]=j}return k},x:function(){for(var k=[],j=Math.round(o/a.g),i=Math.round(s/a.m),g=0;g<a.m;g++)for(var f=0;f<a.g;f++){var d=C("mcBox"),e=d[c];e.left=j*f+"px";e[O]=i*g+"px";d.w=f==a.g-1?o-j*f:j;d.h=g==a.m-1?s-i*g:i;e[r]=d.w+"px";e[q]=d.h+"px";e[B]='url("'+b.e[h]("src")+'") no-repeat -'+f*j+"px -"+g*i+"px";e.position="absolute";K(d,0);E[F](d);k.push(d)}return k},y:function(a,j,k){X=j===true;this.e(a);if(a==b.a&&X&&!b.c){var h=0;if(e[a][g]=="imgLink video"){var d=e[a][Q]("iframe");h=!d.length}else if(e[a][g]=="video"){d=e[a][Q]("video");if(!d.length)d=e[a][Q]("audio");if(d.length&&d[0][c][H]=="none")h=1}h&&this.d(e[a])}if(b.c&&!j||a==b.a)return;if(b.b==2){b.b=0;McVideo.stop(e[b.a])}gb();var f=b.a;b.a=this.n(a);if(k||!i.m)f=0;else f=f>b.a?"10":"9";this.p(f)},n:function(a){if(a>=b.d)a=0;else if(a<0)a=b.d-1;return a},To:function(d,c){if(c&&!a.i)return;this.y(this.n(b.a+d))}};var Z=function(){var a=I(i.sliderId);if(a&&t(a)[d]&&a.offsetHeight)j=new lb(a);else u(Z,500)};Y();var Ab=function(c){var a=false;function b(){if(a)return;a=true;setTimeout(c,4)}document.addEventListener&&document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",b,false);Bb(window,"load",b)};Ab(Z);var Db=function(){if(f){gb();var a=t(f),e=a[d];while(e--)if(a[e][k]=="DIV"){var h=a[e][l][bb](a[e]);h=null}var c=I("mcVideo"+this.Id);if(c){c.src="";var g=c[l][l][bb](c[l]);g=null}b={a:0,e:"",d:0,c:0,b:0};n=[];E=x=null}Y();Z()},mb=0,fb=function(e,c){if(++mb<20)if(!j||typeof tooltip==p)u(function(){fb(e,c)},300);else for(var b=t(x),a=0;a<b[d];a++)b[a].onmouseover=function(){tooltip.pop(this,e(parseInt(this[h]("rel"))),c)}};return{displaySlide:function(c,b,a){j.y(c,b,a)},next:function(){j.To(1)},previous:function(){j.To(-1)},getAuto:function(){return a.i},thumbnailPreview:function(b,a){mb=0;fb(b,a)},switchAuto:function(){if(a.i=!a.i)j.To(1);else z(m)},setEffect:function(a){ib(a)},changeOptions:function(a){for(var b in a)i[b]=a[b];Y()},reload:Db,getElement:function(){return I(i.sliderId)}}}
```

```css
#sliderFrame, #sliderFrame div {
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
#sliderFrame 
{
    width:700px;
 height:300px;
    margin:0 auto; /*center-aligned*/
 margin-top:20px;
}

#slider, #slider .sliderInner {
    width:700px;height:300px;/* Must be the same size as the slider images */
    border-radius:3px;
}

#slider {
    background-color:white;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto; /*center-aligned*/
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #999999;
}

/* the link style (if an image is wrapped by a link) */
#slider a.imgLink, #slider .video {
    z-index:2;
    cursor:pointer;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;left:0px;border:0;padding:0;margin:0;
    width:100%;height:100%;
}
#slider .video {
    background:transparent url(video.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

/* Caption styles */
#slider .mc-caption {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    padding:10px 0;/* 10px will increase the height.*/
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;top:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    font: bold 14px/20px Arial;
    color:#EEE;
    text-align:center;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
#slider .mc-caption a {
    color:#FB0;
}
#slider .mc-caption a:hover {
    color:#DA0;
}


/* ------ built-in navigation bullets wrapper ------*/
#slider .navBulletsWrapper  {
    top:300px;
    text-align:center;
    background:none;
    position:relative;
    z-index:3;
}

/* each bullet */
#slider .navBulletsWrapper div 
{
    width:11px; height:11px;
    font-size:0;color:White;/*hide the index number in the bullet element*/
    background:transparent url(bullet.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    display:inline-block; *display:inline; zoom:1;
    overflow:hidden;cursor:pointer;
    margin:0 6px;/* set distance between each bullet*/
}

#slider .navBulletsWrapper .active {background-position:0 -11px;}


/* --------- Others ------- */

#slider img, #slider>b, #slider a>b {
    position:absolute; border:none; display:none;
}

#slider .sliderInner {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
}

#slider>a, #slider video, #slider audio {display:none;}
#slider div {-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);transform: translate3d(0,0,0);}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link href="css/js-image-slider-products.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="css/js-image-slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<style>

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
    from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
    to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

</style>
</head>


<body>

<h2>1st Modal</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="modal-button" href="#myModal1">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <h2>Modal Header 1</h2>
    </div>
    
    <div class="modal-body">
    
     <div id="sliderFrame">
        <div id="slider">
           <img src="http://humipack.in/images/wsg1.jpg" height="300px" width="700px" />
            <img src="http://humipack.in/images/wsg2.jpg"  height="300px" width="700px" alt="" />
            <img src="http://humipack.in/images/wsg3.jpg" height="300px" width="700px" alt="#htmlcaption" />
            <img src="http://humipack.in/images/wsg4.jpg" height="300px" width="700px" />
        </div>
        
    </div>


      <p>1st Modal Content</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<h2>2nd Modal</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button class="modal-button" href="#myModal2">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <h2>Modal Header 2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    
         <div id="sliderFrame">
        <div id="slider">
            <img src="http://humipack.in/images/wsg1.jpg" height="300px" width="700px" />
            <img src="http://humipack.in/images/wsg2.jpg"  height="300px" width="700px" alt="" />
            <img src="http://humipack.in/images/wsg3.jpg" height="300px" width="700px" alt="#htmlcaption" />
            <img src="http://humipack.in/images/wsg4.jpg" height="300px" width="700px" />
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
      <p>2nd Modal Content</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script>

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.querySelectorAll("button.modal-button");

// All page modals
var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
 btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
    modal.style.display = "block";
 }
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
 spans[i].onclick = function() {
    for (var index in modals) {
      if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";    
    }
 }
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
     for (var index in modals) {
      if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";    
     }
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

i have tried to change the modal content class to `modal-content1` and `modal-content2` but to no avail.

please suggest a solution to load the images in the image slider in the 2nd modal..

Comment: Can you fix up your post to get it working in the code editor, so we can test/debug easier?

Comment: Please check that your slider library provides two slider's on one page or not?

Comment: @FrankerZ  please check the code snippet

Comment: @Swanand thanks for your suggest.... i tried the code at http://www.menucool.com/1075/Add-multiple-sliders-to-one-page and corrected my code ...

Comment: @Amit, It worked or not?

Comment: @Swanand .. it works great.... thanks for your suggestion..

Comment: Glad to help you.